# Terminology: Does the meaning of "dynamic width" have a consensus?

Tags: html, css, terminology

First of all, I don't know if **this question may fit better on another SE site**. Please flag if you think it should be migrated.

---

### Background

Leading from my answer at [Center fixed div with dynamic width (CSS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17069435/center-fixed-div-with-dynamic-width-css/17070034#17070034), I observe on comments that there is a kind of misunderstanding due to the term *dynamic with*.

There are also [over 5k questions on SO regarding this term](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[css]+dynamic+width). On the 90% I reviewed this misunderstanding seems to happen to.

It seems clear for everybody that **"dynamic width"** refers to *adaptable width*, but there are at least 2 possible cases:

1. The element adapts to it's parent width (i.e, `width: 90%`)
2. The element adapts to it's content size (i.e., `display: inline-block`)

### The question

There is a consensus at the community for the meaning of *dynamic width*?

Comment: For me dynamic means that it is not defined. So (2)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli "no defined" could be `width: auto` (so adapting to parent)

Comment: It really depends on context. A div with width auto means 100%.

Comment: i mean not specifically set to a ***value***. Using the docs i mean not having a `length` or `percentage` set (*https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/width#Values*).

Comment: (*but this is just **my** perception, not the consensus*)

Comment: So: [initial value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial_value) (`auto`) or a *[keyword value](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-box-3/#the-width-and-height-properties)*. This can refer to case (1) or case (2) so makes sense with the background of the question: *both meanings are valid*.

Comment: This question requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: @Paulie_D while it *generates discussion*, it doesn't require it. Does a consensus exist? A "yes" or "no" referenced to some trustable sources is enought.

Comment: Discussion questions are still off-topic...as are requests for off-site sources. We may *quote* a source when providing answers to specific, answerable, programming issues...which this is not.

Comment: @Paulie_D Asking about *the definition of a term* seems very specific, but I know you are meaning if it generates discussion is likely there isn't an specific answer. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @Paulie_D Should the question fit with SO standards asking if *there is a formal definition of the term*? I'm curious about how to ask this while avoiding generating discussion or needing it (thus avoiding go off-topic)

Comment: I'm inclined to think not I'd have to think more on it.

Comment: Sorry about my limitations with english, your last comment sounds [confusing to me](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278948/is-stack-overflow-over-polite). Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No, there isn't.

There isn't any source or reference that formally defines the term, thus both cases apply. To avoid misunderstanding, explain on the context of a question or assertion if it refers to *the parent* or *the content*.