# I can´t center my <div> and I don´t understand why

Tags: html, css

I´m trying to center the image.

I´m sure it´s a pretty easy solution, but I´ve tried several solutions besides starting from scratch 3 times.

```
#main_image {
  background-color: bisque;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I´ve already tried margin: o auto , text-align: center, positioning relative and absolute. https://codepen.io/lordrott/pen/GbJOQo

Comment: Also see [Center a position:fixed element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005954/center-a-positionfixed-element) and [Center fixed div with dynamic width (CSS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17069435/center-fixed-div-with-dynamic-width-css).

Comment: "please replace below code this is working. you can just add left:0 and right:0 in #main_image id"

#main_image {
  background-color: bisque;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

Answer (score 1):

Change your position to relative in the css file in the #main_image field.That should work.

```css
#main_image {
  background-color: bisque;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively,

```
#main_image {
  background-color: bisque;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  #main_image{
       position: relative;
       left: 300px;
       top:50px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your applied style. Just add this:

```
/* Keep your applied style*/
figure {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Or add this to your image

```
#main_image {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **This is your solution**

```
#main_image {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: bisque;
}
```